# Pass the value of a SELECT to a Javascript function via the onchange event?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom

I have a HTML page that contains a search box containing a number of textboxes.

The first part of the search box is a **SELECT** dropdown list that contains a variety of report types.  Each report type requires 1 or more of textboxes to be filled in to filter the query results.  My goal is hide the textboxes that are not required by the current report type.

How do I pass the currently selected **value** from the **SELECT** to the Javascript function via the **onchange** event?

```
<select name="report_type" onchange="hide();">
<option value="full_history">Full History</option>
<option value="partial_history">Partial History</option>            
</select>
```

Comment: Question is misinforming. You write it's a PHP question, talk about SELECT, which drove me in thinking you are talking about requests to a database.

Comment: @Alexander - I dropped references to PHP

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<select name="report_type" onchange="hide(this.value);">
<option value="full_history">Full History</option>
<option value="partial_history">Partial History</option>            
</select>
```

When doing this the function have whatever value the select currently has.

Comment: I know this is old but maybe someone will see it - I'm trying to do something like this, but I want to pass the value that is defined in the option tag, rather than the "value" itself. How would I do that? --- For example, in the above code, I want to pass "full_history" (as in value="full_history"), but this.value is passing "Full History".

Comment: @ZeekLTK it sounds like the options don't have the `value` attribute set, and are therefore taking the text from the option itself. If you put your code in another question then it may provide more insight than I can gain from simply a comment.

Comment: Thanks Gabe, it was too late at night I guess, I accidentally left out or deleted the equal sign, so it was just value"full_history" (using the above example). Once I fixed the syntax (to value="full_history") it is passing what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function f1()
{
var obj1= document.getElementById("img");
var obj2= document.getElementById("s1");
obj1.src=obj2.value;
}

Select Image:
    <select id="s1" onchange="f1()">
        <option value="img1.jpg">img1.jpg</option>
        <option value="img2.jpg">img2.jpg</option>
        <option value="img3.jpg">img3.jpg</option>
        <option value="img4.jpg">img4.jpg</option>

    </select> <br><br>
    <img id='img' src="img1.jpg" height="500" width="500">
```