# my cascading combo boxes are sending wrong values

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a from with drop down boxes with options, which once selected will change the values of the next drop down box.

- If i select the first training option, both dates are sent through the form to my email address just fine.
- But if i select the social media workshop or any below, the dates come through as the 2nd or 18th September, which are the values of the first option and not the ones that I have set for this particular label.

I call this `<body onload="setup()">` Javascript:

```
function setup(){
   var select1 = document.getElementById('searchType');
   var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

   for (i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) 
   {
       if (selects[i].id != this.id) {
           selects[i].style.display = 'none';
       }
      document.getElementById(select2).style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('textAreaSearchBox').style.display = 'block';
    };
}
```

Css:

```
#socialmedia, #advancedmarketing, #textAreaSearchBox, #firstaid {
display: none;}
```

Html:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

<label for="phone">What kind of training?</label>
<select id="searchType" name="training" class="fixed-size-drop">
<option value="intromarketing">Introduction to Marketing</option>
<option value="socialmedia">Social Media Workshop</option>
<option value="advancedmarketing">Advanced Marketing Workshop</option>
<option value="firstaid">First Aid Training</option></select>

<label for="date">Choose your Date:</label>
<select id="intromarketing" name="date" class="fixed-size-drop2">
<option value="2ndsept" name="2ndsept">2nd sept 2014</option>
<option value="18thsept" name="18thsept">18th sept 2014</option></select>

<select id="socialmedia" class="fixed-size-drop2">
<option value="id">11th sept 2014</option>
<option value="18thsept">18th sept 2014</option></select>

<select id="advancedmarketing" class="fixed-size-drop2">
<option value="name">9th sept 2014</option>    
<option value="organization">25th sept 2014</option></select>

<select id="firstaid" class="fixed-size-drop2">
<option value="3rdsept" name="3rdsept">3rd September 2014</option>    
<option value="16thsept" name="16thsept">16th September 2014</option></select>
<input type="submit" class="ubutton" value="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the uploaded form:  http://coffeemachines4u.co.uk/test-form.php

I have been scratching my head for a few hours so if anybody could point me in the right direction i would be extremely thankful :)

Comment: Unless i made a mistake in editing your answer the variable  `select2` is never defined. The code in the link you provided seems to be not identical; for example this line from the linked example `var select2 = this.value.toLowerCase();` was not in the code you posted here. AFAICT this line `select1.onchange = function() { ...` is also missing. Please edit this question to match it with the code you posted as a link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass the value of a SELECT to a Javascript function via the onchange event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478640/pass-the-value-of-a-select-to-a-javascript-function-via-the-onchange-event)

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the name-attribute in of your selectboxes. Only the first select has the name date. If this is invisible it is also there and because of this the form send the date parameter from the date. You can change the name attribute and the vivible of your selectboxes on same time

use this JavaScrip

```
var select1 = document.getElementById('searchType');
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

select1.onchange = function() {
var select2 = this.value.toLowerCase();
for (i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    if (selects[i].id != this.id) {
        selects[i].style.display = 'none';
        selects[i].removeAttribute('name');
    }
}
document.getElementById(select2).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById(select2).name = 'date';
document.getElementById('textAreaSearchBox').style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the name of the four dynamic `select` elements with: `name="date"`.

On `select#searchType` change, you need to disable / enable (DOM element property) the corresponding select(s).